# How to use hexdump to show charaters in different presentations at the same time

Tags: linux, file, shell, hexdump

I am counting the number of characters of files and directory names of an entire directory.

```
find . -printf "%f/n" | sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
    234 _
    162 /
    341 .
    342 0
    156 1
    217 2
     99 3
    ...
```

But I need also a list of decimal, hex **and** normal representation at the same time of the found characters:

Example:

```
066 0x42 'A'
...
090 0x5A 'Z'
```

I have tried `hexdump` with different format options but this didn't work for me.

Can it be done with **hexdump** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it be done with hexdump?

Yes:

```
find . -printf "%f/n" |
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%03d "' -e '/1 "0x%02X "' -e '/1 "%c\n"'
```

See examples at the end of the `hexdump` man page.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation after your answer:

```
find . -printf "%f\n" | sed "s/./&\n/g" | sort | uniq  | tr -d '\n' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%03d "' -e '/1 "0x%02X "' -e '/1 "<%c>\n"'
```

Output:

```
060 0x3C <<>
062 0x3E <>>
058 0x3A <:>
063 0x3F <?>
046 0x2E <.>
097 0x61 <a>
098 0x62 <b>
099 0x63 <c>
100 0x64 <d>
101 0x65 <e>
069 0x45 <E>
102 0x66 <f>
104 0x68 <h>
072 0x48 <H>
105 0x69 <i>
108 0x6C <l>
109 0x6D <m>
110 0x6E <n>
078 0x4E <N>
111 0x6F <o>
195 0xC3 <�>
182 0xB6 <�>
...
```

Comment: Sorry, have missed that you want only unique characters. BTW, you can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`.

Comment: Oops. Another error in my answer (would edit in a minute): in first column I print octal (`%03o`) instead of decimal (`%03d`).

Comment: I also corrected my command and output from octal to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative to hexdump/hd is xxd.** xxd can covert to hex and back. But I warn you with 32bit data and XOR I noticed an error I was getting 46 instead of 41. Also theres an option for uppercase and lowercase hex and out the default is BIG ENDIAN but theres a LITTLE ENDIAN ooption and remember the output is a char string and not the HEX equivalent.

I think the `hexdump -C` command is what you are looking for see `man hexdump` or `man xxd`.

PS> @Dummy00001 what does hexdumps "/1" do? I get the same result if I omit it
@ebart why is there a 'g' character in your sed script replacment operation replaces each char with \n at the end of line(&): "s/./&\n/g"

From link below:
The X/X format is called a count specifier, so 2/4 means 2 instances of a 4 byte (32 bit) value. The %08x format means output the value as an 8 digit hexadecimal number with leading zeros.

**This command is not the answer to your question but shows how hexdump formatting is done:**
hexdump -s 446 -n 64 -v -e '1/1 "%02x" 3/1 " %3d" 1/1 " %02x" 3/1 " %3d" 2/4 "

Comment: man 3 printf man should explain the "1/1" at front of hexdump commands source: https://www.suse.com/c/making-sense-hexdump/ but man 3 printf | grep "/1"
 is nothing on Ubuntu 18 Live

Comment: This was the related question using XOR and hexdump which shows the xxd error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620882/how-to-xor-two-hex-numbers-in-bash-script-xor-encryption/53109103#53109103